# Mongoose error? "Undefined is not a function"

Tags: node.js, mongoose, coffeescript

Before read a lot of times my code because it's throwing me an:

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function
  at facturaCtrl.get (/home/nano/Dev/erp-api/app/controllers/facturasController.coffee:18:13)
```

I oficially get stuck. I'm writing a rest API and this is the first method on this controller, is very simple and i don't know why is tracing me that, here is the piece of code:

```
get: (req, res) ->
    permission = req.user.canModifyFactura

    if not permission
      return res.json new Unauthorized("#{req.user.username} no tiene permisos")

    Factura.find()
      .exec (err, facturas) ->
        if err then return res.json new Internal(err.stack, err.message)
        if not facturas or facturas.length is 0
          return res.json new NotFound("No encontrado")

        res.json new Ok(facturas)
```

The line that trace is pointing me (18):

```
Factura.find()
```

But as i know (and use in other controllers) the `find()` function exists in mongoose... anyway, i think that is a stupid thing but i just don't see the problem before 1 hour. Here is the entire code [Gitlab snippet link](https://gitlab.com/snippets/8995) I don't paste it here because is more than 100 lines of code, so...

**Edit:** the problem are not in the code of the controller, i just don't exported/imported the model correctly. Noob mistake.

Comment: Can you show what is in  `./models/factura`

Comment: I just found the problem 5 minutes ago, I was not importing the model correctly... noob error!